# Oracle Error trying to Create Range Partitioned Table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a partitioned table in Oracle 19c.

```
create table tab1
(
   id        number(10),
   sale_date date
 )
 partition by range ( sale_date )
 (
     partition p1 values less than ( to_date ( '2010/01/01','yyyy/mm/dd'),
     partition p2 values less than ( to_date ( '2010/02/01','yyyy/mm/dd')
  )
```

/

I am getting following error:

ORA-14017: partition bound list contains too many elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the close parentheses around each less than () value:

```
 partition by range ( sale_date )
 (
     partition p1 values less than ( to_date ( '2010/01/01','yyyy/mm/dd')),
     partition p2 values less than ( to_date ( '2010/02/01','yyyy/mm/dd'))
  )
```